# How to use Gronwall's inequality in matrix function?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, inequality, partial-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics

In 1.1.1 of 'The Mathematical Analysis of the Incompressible Euler and Navier-Stokes Equations, Jacob Bedrossian & Vlad Vicol', I don't understand the following estimate

$$\sup_{a\in\mathbb{R}^d}|\nabla_aX(t,a)|\leq \exp(\int_0^t||\nabla u(s)||_{L^{\infty}}ds).$$

$X(\cdot,t):\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}^d$ is the flow map, which has the following property

$$\partial_t X(a,t)=u(t,X(a,t)),$$
where $u(t,x)$ is the velocity field.
I have proved the following identity
$$\partial_t \nabla_a X(t,a)=\nabla_x u(t,x)\cdot\nabla_aX(t,a).$$
It's definitely like the Gronwall's inequality of the scalar function, which is

Assume $u(x),v(x)$ is continue function and
$$u^{'}(x)\leq
v(x)u(x), \forall x\in
[a,b]$$
then we have
$$u(x)\leq u(a)\exp(\int_a^x v(t)dt), \forall x\in [a,b].$$
But in the matrix case, I can not understand how to deduce the result in the book.

Comment: Since we just want an estimate with $|\nabla_a X(t,x)|$, which is a scalar, we can use Grönwall's inequality as usual if $|\nabla_a X(t,x)|$ verifies some inequality itself. It might be useful to know that Grönwall's inequality has an integral form: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality#Integral_form_for_continuous_functions

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have understood it after saw your comment.